# IOSApp unable to install

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution

I try to deploy an app for my company use. So I do  Product->Archive, select the good distribution cert/profil. I upload the file on the web, make the link to the `manifest.plist` to `.ipa` and then I try to install it on my ipad but ... unable to intall:
**UPDATE:** I don't want to install it directly on a Ipad, but download it from an url with the ipad and I'm using entreprise developper program and it work if I directly build it for the ipad

Here the ios console Log :

[image: Here the ios console Log]

I find strange that in the log after

> INVALID >> { 642AFE.... this number is not the same there is in my
>   ipa filename.

I also find strange to get many plist file (distribution, export ...) .

Here the folder i drop to the server :

[image: Here the folder i drop to the server]

Does anyone have some idea ?
thanks by adavance

Comment: which one you have archived using? Development or production?

Comment: you need to add iPad's UDID in order to install app on it in development mode

Comment: Where did you see that option in Xcode? I just click on Product->Archive

Comment: I don't want to install it directly on a Ipad, but download it from an url with the ipad

Comment: which account you are using? developer account or enterprise account?

Comment: Hmm, I'm in a company but we have buy for a mac a developper account at 200$ , but when I archive with Product->Archive Then select Archive-->Distribute App --> I select Entreprise (distribute for your organization) and not Development

Comment: Did your company sign up for an enterprise program or a company App Store developer program - Does your team in Xcode say "XYZ Company (Enterprise)" or "XYZ Company (Company)"?  If it says "(Enterprise)" then you have a problem with your signing (since the error says that the app isn't signed).  If it says "(Company)" then you have a membership that is intended to deliver apps via the App Store.  You can only distribute directly to devices that include the UUID in the provisioning profile.

Comment: Apple Developer Enterprise Program

Comment: Ohh I saw it in the log , also I don't knwo why but sometime I have many ipa files sometime just one . Is it normal to have many (like 8) ipa file ?

Comment: Ok I succeed , I modifiy the manifest.plist , I replace all link to the different .ipa to only one .ipa and it work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the normal developer account then to install the application in device(either directly or from any third party sites) you have to sign the archive file either with development profile of AdHoc distribution profile. Here if you have selected the Appstore distribution certificate and profile then the application will not be able to install in any device.

If the device's UDID is added to the profile(development or AdHoc distribution) then you can install the app directly using Xcode or via an URL.

If you are using the enterprise program and the application is signed with the distribution certificate and profile then the application can be install in any device regardless of the existence of UDID in the profile.

Please check the profile when you are archiving the ipa.

Hope this helps you in some way.

Comment: I know, I'm in the second case, but still don't work

Comment: Can you please check once if you are able to directly install the exported ipa to the iPad?

Comment: It work if i directly send it to the ipad, without particular error. 
But the trouble is : It need to work from an url